# Remove Column by Name with different index of column header

Tags: c#

In my program after import an excel file to datagridview, each sheet have different index of column header which the 1st row is Total Qty & Net Value. I wanted to delete the Total Qty & Net Value column data. Have any ideas on how to achieve this? I tried to remove the column header, but most of it just hide not delete it.

[image]

I got an error using the code below because Total Qty is not column header.

```
for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
 dt.Columns.Remove("TOTAL QTY"); //insert row?
}
```

Comment: Why not :  dt.Columns.Remove("TOTAL QTY");

Comment: Why are you iterating the Rows, here. You can remove a Column by index, if the name is dubious. It should be `21` and `22`, apparently. Try with `dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(1);` or  `DataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(1);`.

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: Or are you maybe trying ot just remove the extra Row containing `TOTAL QTY`, `NET VALUE` etc.?

Comment: @jdweng as i mentioned "Total Qty" is not a column header.

Comment: @Jimi yes I can delete by index but for other excel sheet has different index of "Total Qty" maybe at 32 etc and for your 2nd comment on what condition should I remove bcs different excel file has different length of row and column

Comment: @programmer444 The error said that "TOTAL QTY" is not in column table something. Total Qty is a row not a column header but I want to remove the whole column data

Comment: What is the header in excel?  Does you connection string contains headers?  You can Remove using either a name or a column index (starting at zero).

Comment: All right. But the major points are: 1) Do you want to remove the Columns from a DataTable or a DataGridView? The values in the first row are always `TOTAL QTY` and `NET VALUE`? If yes, you can determine which Column to remove searching the first Row, see what Cell contains the values and get its Index, the remove the Columns by Index. It would be probably better to filter the Data from the beginning, though.

Comment: I want to remove from datatable. Thanks for the suggestion. Gonna try it

Comment: Right. Then try something like: `var badColumns = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Where(c => c.ToString().Contains("TOTAL QTY") | c.ToString().Contains("NET VALUE")).Select((c, i) => i).ToArray();`. You now should have the indexes of the Columns you want to remove from your DataTable.

Comment: I tried that and test to get the index thru MessageBox.Show(badColumns.ToString()); And it shows system.int32

Comment: `badColumns.ToString()`? No, no, what string. Those are the indexes you need to use to delete your Columns: `foreach (var col in badColumns) { dt.Columns.RemoveAt(col); }`

Comment: OMG thanks i got it!